# Creating Slash Commands in Microsoft Teams apps

Tags: microsoft-teams

I have been trying to find a way to access my Microsoft teams app through a slash command. I have a working messaging extension app that I can access and use with an @mention, but I was wondering if there was a way to enable my messaging extension to be invoked with a slash command from the search bar. In a way I am trying to create custom slash commands, but could not find anyone with similar problems. Can someone please let me know if it is possible and if so, How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, you can not create your own slash commands which are accessible from search bar.
[image]

Only option is to add messaging extension which you are already doing.
[image]

Comment: Okay. Thank you!

Comment: How come? I'm also looking for a way to do this. The Whobot app defines its own `/who` command. I find it strange that this app somehow can and others can't.

Comment: @Mig82 - Who bot is a first party integration, this feature is currently not available for third party developers. Currently 3P developer can use @ mention to invoke messaging extensions. Please feel free to raise this as feature request on [User Voice portal](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/ad198462-1c1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472).